# WordPress - replicate same globals, query vars and query for an alternate endpoint

Tags: rewrite-rules, endpoints

We are building a hybrid mobile app for a website.

The app will display a minimal version of the webpage, for example if the website displays post title, post content, sidebar, widgets, etc, then the app would show just post title and the post content for the same post.

Take for example the single post page which is typically rendered by `single.php`.

For a URL `www.example.com/sample-post`, the mobile app will visit a custom **HTML** endpoint `www.example.com/minimal/sample-post` which will be rendered by `minimal-single.php`

The problem is that the WordPress loop doesn't work inside `minimal-single.php` because the query variables and the query that is set up for `single.php` is not set for this endpoint `/minimal/sample-post` (`mimnimal-single.php`).

You might say I could use a custom `WP_Query` to loop through the posts but at the moment there are few restrictions which doesn't allow us to do this.

Is there a way in which we can instruct WordPress to initialise the same globals, query vars and the query used by an endpoint for some other endpoint?

I want to extend this to WooCommerce where the web version can use `/product/sunglasses` and the app can use `/minimal/product/sunglasses` and use the WooCommerce loop directly without using `WP_Query`.

Comment: Have you tried/considered using a [custom rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)?

Comment: @SallyCJ I went through the custom rewrite rules but I'm not sure how to implement it. Can you assist with an example?